# In what type of fie can I stored json data on client machine?

Tags: c#, windows, json, file, file-format

I am creating a local database which keeps json dump. 
I can store it in txt or xml files but I want to use correct file format to store json.

Which is the standred file format for storing json?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it will just did not know if its stranded one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a standard extension, as I am a linux user, but when I give them extensions, I just use *.json...

Comment: Thanks... I found the information here http://filext.com/file-extension/json

Congrats for your 1000